# display civicrm image in drupal views

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, civicrm

How to display an image stored in civicrm database in Drupal views?
I have a webform through which user registers and details are stored in civicrm db. I have created a view which displays the user data but when it comes to images it only displays URL of image. Is there a way to display image also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The civicrm image field is a url. To make it display as an image you will need to surround it with an `<img>` tag using the "rewrite" option in views.
In your view click on the field and check "Rewrite the output of this field"
Enter this text: `<img src="[image_URL]" alt="Contact Image" style="max-width: 200px" />`
The "alt" and "style" attributes are optional and you can set max-width to whatever you want (but if you omit it the images will all be the uploaded size).